# unable to set hidden field content from div html content on fullscreen iPad Mobile Safari

Tags: html, ipad

Thanks for spending time to read this

I have a form where is call a JS function to copy the html content of a DIV to a hidden form field so that I can submit this with the form. It works fine on desktop webkit broswers and also on mobile safari on iPad. However when I run the application in fullscreen mode (by saving a shortcut on home screen), this does not work.

Here's my code

JS function:

```
function update_script_in()//copies scripts and submits the form
{
    $("#script_in").html($("#scriptContent").html());
    $('#ResiForm').submit();
}
```

form submission:

```
<input type=submit value="Submit" onclick="update_script_in()">
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: iOS does not render JavaScript the same in Safari as it does full screen web apps.  Perhaps it is the particular method you are trying to use to invoke the function?

Comment: Thanks @TheAccordance , is there any specific way I should call this so it works in the full screen mode ? What I've used is pretty much standard juery .html(htmlString) usage

Comment: What I have found is that the following causes it to break in full screen mode (works fine normally in mobile safari etc) 

$("#script_in").html($("#scriptContent").html());

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old, but after googling around to solve the same issue for me, I have not found a solution. Looks like some weird behaviour from iPad (easily reproducible, no way to fix, at least that I found): the target input field gets changed indeed, but the posted value is the original one (???)

So just in case a workaround is useful to somebody, instead of applying the changes from the contenteditable div on form submit, I apply the changes whenever the div is changed (no on change event for contenteditable divs, so really it is done on blur event):

```
<div id="editor_inline_core_body" class="inputbox editor-inline" contenteditable>[initial value here]</div>
<input type="hidden" id="jform_core_body" name="jform[core_body]" value="[ initial value here]" />
<script>
        jQuery('#editor_inline_core_body').blur(function() {
        var value = jQuery('#editor_inline_core_body').html();
        jQuery('#jform_core_body').val(value);
        return true;
    });
</script>
```

Less efficient, but at least it works. If you want a bit more of efficiency, you can check old and new values using also focus event, but at least I do not think it is a big deal or worth the added complexity.